# Get Arrow in qTip

Tags: jquery, tooltip, qtip

How can I add arrow in qTip. So far I have

```
$('.jym').qtip( {
            content: 'Ok', 
            style: { 
                name: 'cream' ,
                border: {
                    width: 3,
                    radius: 8,
                    color: '#6699CC'
                }
            },
            position: {
                corner: {
                    target: 'leftMiddle',
                    tooltip: 'rightMiddle'
                }
            }
        });
```

The generated tooltip is:
[image]

But I need this:[image]

I went through the documentation but didn't understand how to get this arrow.

I really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try adding

```
  style: {
    tip: {
      corner: 'leftMiddle'
    }
```

to the existing list of options

http://craigsworks.com/projects/qtip/docs/tutorials/#position